# Why is printf not using scientific notation?

Tags: c, printf, pow

I understand that this is a common problem. However I can't find a solid straight answer.

```
16 ^ 54 = 1.0531229167e+65 (this is the result I want)
```

When I use `pow(16,54)`, I get:

> 105312291668557186697918027683670432318895095400549111254310977536.0

Code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){

   double public;
   double a = 16;
   double b = 54;
   public = (pow(a,b));

   printf("%.21f\n", public);
}
```

Code executed with:

> gcc main.c -lm

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So you want scientific notation?

Comment: Also read about the `g` format specifier.

Comment: Your code is exhibits UB (*`main()`* returns an *`int`* - not a *`void`* or anything else no matter what appears to 'work' no matter how many times or how many systems it's run on). ...which I see the answer now points out. Good. Anyway UB is bad news but fortunately this one is easy to fix.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Several things:

- Use `%.10e` format for scientific notation with `printf` for a printout with ten digits after the dot,
- Return an `int` from your `main`,
- Consider not using `public` to name a variable, on the chance that your program would need to be ported to C++, where `public` is a keyword.

Here is how you can fix your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

   double p;
   double a = 16;
   double b = 54;
   p = (pow(a,b));

   printf("%.10e\n", p);
   return 0;
}
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/hEpJYz)

Comment: `public` is not a keyword in C. :)   Although its use will be problematic if this code ever moves to C++

Comment: @abelenky You're right, I missed the tag. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 14):

Have you tried:

```
printf("%e\n", public);
```

The `%e` specifier is for scientific notation, as [described in the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Answer (score 4):

If you need scientific notation you need to use the `%e` [format specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf):

```
printf("%e\n", public);
        ^^
```

Also, `public` is a [keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) in C++ and so it would be a good idea to avoid that and any other *keywords* in case this code needs to be portable.

Comment: Amusing puns: *public* [is a] *keyword* (and *public* is in the ghastly C++), *keywords* in *case* (also a keyword in both C and C++ and others too). It's a great idea though to write code with C++ names just to prevent the C++ conversions!  But you're right that if there is any chance there will be a desire to port it then better not do that.