# fscanf read very small number in matrix as zero

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to use `fscanf` to read matrix data in a text file and do some matrix*vector calculation in C.
However I noticed that `fscanf` read very small number such as -2.22E-10 to zero. Here is the code for reading the matrix from "D1_1.txt" file.

```
file = fopen("D1_1.txt", "r");
    for (j = 0; j < matcols; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < matrows; i++) {
            if (!fscanf(file, "%lf", &(data->D1_1data)[j + i*matcols]));  
        }
    }
fclose(file);
```

And here is the screenshot image of the original data

[image]

And below, screenshot of the data read by fscanf (I use fprintf to write another txt file from C code)

[image]

As you can see, large number can be correctly read by `fscanf` but not very small number such as 5.92e-10.

Is %lf not a good choice here ? What should I use to read all the numbers correctly ?

Thanks,

Comment: What was the format used in fprintf?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Same as %lf

Comment: *I use fprintf* - it is likely the problem, and not `fscanf`.

Comment: So you only get 6 digits.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287974/why-is-printf-not-using-scientific-notation

Comment: Thanks. Eugene. what should I use for fprintf instead of %lf  ?

Comment: Check the linked answer. It explains how to make it print in scientific notation.

Comment: Thank you all. I just confirmed that `fscanf` is not an issue. `fprintf` should use with scientific notation like %.10e to print the small number correctly.

Comment: _Side note:_ Based on your data image, `matcols` is 4 and `matrows` is 8. Normally, you want row elements to be physically contiguous. But, AFAICT, you're reading the matrix in transposed. You may want to flip the order of your `for` loops. Also, I know it's taught in school to use `i` and `j`, but [IMO, based on experience], it's better to use something more descriptive (e.g.) `irow` and `icol`